# Permissions error for a signed Java applet when including external JAR files

Tags: java, security, applet, code-signing, mixed-code

I have a signed Java applet. And it works fine. But now I have to integrate some 3rd party JAR files with it. When I test it from Eclipse, the whole thing works correctly. But when I test it as an applet, it gives me a **java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission ...)**

I thought this was because those 3rd party JAR files don't have a java.policy.applet within them. But manually adding the policy file doesn't get rid of the error.

What am I missing? Thanks!

============================

All the 3rd party JAR files sit on the server filesystem like so: A.jar, B.jar, C.jar. And I include them in the applet tag like so:

```
<applet
    archive="my.jar,A.jar,B.jar,C.jar">
</applet>
```

Also, in the MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF file in my.jar, I include those JAR files like so:

```
Class-Path: A.jar,B.jar,C.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sign these jars as well, if they are attempting restricted operations.

Comment: Also note that since 6u19 (the current secure release of Java SE 6 at the time of writing) users will typically get a warning earlier: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html / I have to make my usual comment that you really should know what you are doing before signing code.